# Discovering list of all Queue Managers through java programs in WMQ

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Discovering list of all Queue Managers through java programs.

Hi team how can we Discover list of all Queue Managers through java programs.

To start with i have created 2 Queue managers and a cluster of 3 queue managers.

I need to write a monitoring application for WMQ. IS there an alternative to PCF?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try out the open source project MQ Port Scan?
http://www.capitalware.biz/mqps_overview.html